# Could anyone explain SimpleExpandableListAdapter 's parameters and how they are implementing and working

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. Could anyone PLEASE explain the parameters inside SimpleExpandableListAdapter. i can tell "this" means this context, "groupData" & "childData" are obviously variable declared. please explain the rest why they are used like this and how they are working?

```
 mAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                groupData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "parent" },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 },
                childData,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                new String[] {"child"},
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }
                );
     setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the summary on [developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html)

```
public SimpleExpandableListAdapter (Context context, 
     List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, 
     int groupLayout, 
     String[] groupFrom, 
     int[] groupTo, 
     List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData, 
     int childLayout, 
     String[] childFrom, 
     int[] childTo)
```

Added in API level 1
Constructor

Parameters

- **context:**   The context where the ExpandableListView associated with this SimpleExpandableListAdapter is running
- **groupData:** A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one group in the list. The Maps contain the data for each group, and should include all the entries specified in "groupFrom"
- **groupLayout:**   resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for a group. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "groupTo"
- **groupFrom:** A list of keys that will be fetched from the Map associated with each group.
- **groupTo:**   The group views that should display column in the "groupFrom" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the groupFrom parameter.
- **childData:** A List of List of Maps. Each entry in the outer List corresponds to a group (index by group position), each entry in the inner List corresponds to a child within the group (index by child position), and the Map corresponds to the data for a child (index by values in the childFrom array). The Map contains the data for each child, and should include all the entries specified in "childFrom"
- **childLayout:**   resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for a child. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "childTo"
- **childFrom:** A list of keys that will be fetched from the Map associated with each child.
- **childTo:**   The child views that should display column in the "childFrom" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the childFrom parameter.